# how to on selenium plugin in storm crawler

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

How we can configure to on selenium plugin in storm crawler, for example in archetype project of that?
There is a [code](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/selenium/SeleniumProtocol.java) for using selenium in storm crawler. But i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Try implementing the code if get any error then post here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial on how to crawl with Selenium on the [DigitalPebble blog](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.com/2017/04/crawl-dynamic-content-with-selenium-and.html). Try to reproduce the steps of the tutorial for a start.